# How to keep appium capabilities in json file and call in code

Tags: json, appium

Following is my appium capability set to run a test

```
cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.0"); 
            cap.setCapability("deviceName", "mygeny510");
            cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.dialer");
            cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity");

            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```

I want to keep the capabilities in a apm.json file

```
[
  {
    "platformName": "android",
    "appPackage":"com.android.dialer",
    "appActivity": "com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity",
    "deviceName": "mygeny510"
  }
]
```

Now can anyone help to call the apm.json into the code instead writing each capabilities by using cap.setcapability(,)

Answer (score 0):

You can place all the desired capabilities on to a seperate file and load the file in an other file for referencing it.

For eg,
I have the desired capabilities in `env.rb`

```
def abc

      {
          caps:

              {

                  platformName: "iOS",
                  deviceName: "",
                  udid: "",
                  app: (File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "")),
                  bundleId: "",
                  automationName: "XCUITest",
                  xcodeOrgId: "",
                  xcodeSigningId: "",
                  platformVersion: "9.3.2",
                  noReset: "true",
                  fullReset: "false",
                  showIOSLog: "true"
                 }
      }


    end
```

Now you can go to the file where you want to launch this desired capabilities. For this, you would need to load the .json file into this file. I have used `require_relative` to load the file in order to call the method. Once you do that, you can start the session with

```
def AnyName
  Appium::Driver.new(abc)   #Pass capabilities for appium inside the driver
  Appium.promote_appium_methods Object #Makes all appium_lib methods accessible from steps
  $driver.start_driver  #Starts appium driver before the tests begin
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You kept all the capabilities in a ruby file not a json format, I am not getting how can I achieve the same in Java, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure why do you want to store the desired capabilities in `.json` format? You can always have a `java` file that contains the desired capabilities and call the same in an other file. Is there a special reason that you want to store it in `.json`?

Comment: I understoof your point, we can have method under a java file with all capabilities and call them when need,I dn't have such need to keep it in a json file, just got to know we can keep in json file and call them through java, so wondering if we can do that or not?

Comment: May be Yes! You can. I was thinking, If I am doing it in ruby, I had store all the capabilities in `json` and convert it to a `hash_table` and load the desired capabilities. Just theoretical thought, Haven't done it yet.!